# DotNetNuke Module Packaging

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, module-packaging

Does anyone know of any simple, concise tutorials for packaging DotNetNuke modules for DotNetNuke 4 and DotNetNuke 5? Preferably something concerning DotNetNuke 5.4, since that's what I'm running.

The examples that I've seen all assume background knowledge, or they are about short-cuts to the existing process. I'm a beginner, so I need the simple basics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, it's kind of a nightmare the first time.

I started here: [Creating a DotNetNuke® Module - For Absolute Beginners!](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/Creating_A_DNNModule.aspx) It's DNN 4.x, so a few of the conventions may have changed, but it will probably be close enough to get you going.

[Creating a DNN Module and Understanding DNN Architectural Approach](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/LCTDNNModDev.aspx) goes into more detail:

I suppose the important concept is: you're writing a `WebControl` using the MVC pattern. The DNN Module Wizard will create a "view" page for you, and you add code to suit.

Answer (score 1):

there's some good resources here for info on packages:

- http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Blogs/tabid/825/EntryId/1140/Packaging-and-protecting-your-DotNetNuke%C2%AE-Module.aspx
  by Michael Washington   (mentioned above)
- http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Development/Forge/ModuleReports/tabid/970/EntryId/453/DotNetNuke-4-3-Starter-Kit-and-Item-Templates.aspx
  by Shaun Walker

Simple basics...

When you start with the DNN module template in Visual Studio there's a standard .dnn file there. this file must be modified to include all files needed to run the module (resx, images, dlls, ascx, .sqldataprovider) without any of the sourcecode files (.cs, .vb).

zip all of the files mentioned in the .dnn file up with the dnn file (all files in root of the zip) and submit it to the upload new module page (logged in as Host).

the zip is automatically extracted, the .dnn file is read and all files are placed in the appropriate places.

resources for creating packages:

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/DnnModulePackager.aspx
- http://www.mitchelsellers.com/blogs/articletype/articleview/articleid/200.aspx

by looking at these you can also further your understanding of package creation.

i'm using 4.9 currently so someone may want to correct me on changes that i'm unaware of.

Answer (score 0):

Google for Michael Washington and / or Mitchel Sellers and they have excellent work on Module Development.

Mark Breen
Ireland

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start is use the IFrame module. It's all code behind so no compile needed before deployment. Look in the dnn file to see where the files are copied to.

Answer (score 0):

Chris Hammond has recently written two blog posts on dotnetnuke.com about packaging modules,  you should really have a look that those, they are super, he tells you how to set up  your environment and how to create a C#Template for your modules.

thanks
Mark

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to look at https://github.com/dazinator/DnnPackager which is a NuGet package that when added to your module project, automates production of the install zip, and has other features